# Where does Sword of the Stars: The Pit saves screenshots?

Tags: sword-of-the-stars-the-pit

I took few screenshots in game and I can't find them anywhere. There doesn't seem to be a screenshots folder anywhere inside the folder where game is installed. I also searched *My Documents* folder and haven't found anything related to that either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows 7, I found them in `C:\Users\$USER\AppData\Roaming\Sword of the Stars - The Pit\ScreenShots`

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\"User"\ApplicationData\Sword of the Stars - The Pit\ScreenShots for the Windows XP.